Even if the user exists, I get error: role "postgress" does not exist
I am trying to run a postgres container and connect my NestJS app to it using TypeORM.
The following is my Dockerfile:
FROM postgres:16
ENV POSTGRES_DB=my-db-name
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgress
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword

And the following is my app.module.ts:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CalendarController } from './calendar.controller';
import { CalendarService } from './calendar.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Slot } from './entities/slot.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgress',
      password: 'mypassword',
      database: 'my-db-name',
      entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Slot]),
  ],
  controllers: [CalendarController],
  providers: [CalendarService],
})
export class AppModule {}


But when I run my NestJS app, I get this error:
[Nest] 51550  - 09/25/2024, 4:44:04 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 51550  - 09/25/2024, 4:44:04 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +50ms
[Nest] 51550  - 09/25/2024, 4:44:04 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
error: role "postgress" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/mohsen/enpal/my-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:368:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/mohsen/enpal/my-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:187:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/mohsen/enpal/my-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:102:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mohsen/enpal/my-app/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:191:23)

I have also run \du command from terminal within my postresql container to list the list of users and its output is as below:
coding-challenge=# \du
                             List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
 postgress | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS

It seems to me everything is correct but my NestJS app says the above error.

Are you 200% sure about the name postgress with double s ?

Yes I want to have ss instead of s, if possible.


Why? You end up two similar named roles that do the same thing. 2) Are you sure you are connecting to correct Postgres  instance(the one with postgress)? 3) Try with role name postgres and see what you connect to?


Slightly off-topic: Why do you even use a superuser role for your application? That should be avoided

Problem was that I had already a PostgreSQL running on my system. I stopped it.
